# Cpu restarting when hit 75 C

Tags: cpu-load

I need to fix my ubuntu 20.04 when the process hit 75 C it's restarting automatically, how I can prevent this, from my sensor it shows package id 0 when hit 75C

My Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz

Ram 16 Gb Corsair

Hd NVME

Mainboard Asrock 1151 B365M PRO4

VGA  [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590]

My PSU Cooler Master 650

Comment: For some CPUs it is too high.  It is unrelated to Ubuntu. It is rebooted by BIOS or by hardware.

Comment: The BIOS may be causing the restart instead of Ubuntu. What's the make and model part number of your PC? Find the latter printed on the same sticker as your serial number. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: also make and model number of your CPU.

Comment: That CPU is up to 100 C. But radeon may have lower. Does the GPU fan work?

Comment: Yes, it's working without any issue for GPU fan